# Ionic creator page inside an Android WebView

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, android-webview

I want to know if it's possible to create a page (example login) with Ionic creator web site (see http://ionic.io/products/creator), download it as .zip archive (always via their web site), and than open the index.html page inside an Android webView. I need of this page only for a "GUI" of a web application (on a server) that a want to execute inside my native Android app (creating an hybrid app).

I have tryed to call this index.html page inside the WebView of my Android app but I obtain "404 - not found" message.

This is the index.html page inside the .zip archive of this my Ionic Creator little project that I have obtained from their web site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8">
           <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
           <title></title>

           <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

           <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) 
           <script src="cordova.js"></script> 
           -->

           <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below                   and remove the CSS includes above
           <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
           -->

           <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">

           <style type="text/css">
               .platform-ios .manual-ios-statusbar-padding{
                   padding-top:20px;
               }
               .manual-remove-top-padding{
                   padding-top:0px; 
               }
               .manual-remove-top-padding .scroll{
                   padding-top:0px !important;
               }
               ion-list.manual-list-fullwidth div.list,   .list.card.manual-card-fullwidth {
                   margin-left:-10px;
                   margin-right:-10px;
  }
       ion-list.manual-list-fullwidth div.list > .item, .list.card.manual-card-fullwidth > .item {
        border-radius:0px;
        border-left:0px;
    border-right: 0px;
  }
  .show-list-numbers-and-dots ul{
    list-style-type: disc;
    padding-left:40px;
  }
  .show-list-numbers-and-dots ol{
    list-style-type: decimal;
    padding-left:40px;
  }
</style>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/routes.js"></script>

<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>

<!-- Only required for Tab projects w/ pages in multiple tabs 
<script src="lib/ionicuirouter/ionicUIRouter.js"></script>
-->

  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
     <div style="">
     <div style="">
       <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
       <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you linked it properly? Did you placed it in the www folder? Can you show us our java code where you load the webview into?

Comment: OK, I have followed this guide: 
http://docs.usecreator.com/docs/exporting 

and now, after some npm command, I have my first Ionic creator project that works.
Now my question is, if I want to add another page to my project using Ionic Creator, what is the right procedure to follow? I must modifying the project on Ionic creator web page, download the entire project again and linked it with Ionic CLI commands?

Thanks in advance.